# creating new object in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

so im making an array list of type Name, im trying to create 2 new objects that i can add to the list, so that it makes two different sets of full names.

```java
ArrayList<Name> register = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <4 ; i++) {
            
    Name objt = new Name();
    objt.setFirstName(firstName);
    objt.setFamilyName(familyName );
    register.add(objt);
```

```java
Name person = new Name();
for (int i = 0; i <3 ; i++) {
    person = register.get(i);
    System.out.println(person.getFullName());
```

Comment: *"im trying to create 2 new objects"* Where are you trying to do that? Sorry, I don't see it.

Comment: If you add 2 new objects to the same list, how is that "two different sets" of names? It's one list of names, not two. If you want two sets, you'd need another list.

Comment: sorry, basically im trying to make an array list of names which include two string objects firstname and familyname, im trying to run a loop that will ask for the first and family name twice, then out put them within the same array list

Comment: Repeat the code you have in your first code block. You don't have to declare obit again, but you do need to assign it a ``new Name()``.

Comment: What problem are you having doing this?

Comment: im using a scanner class to create the 2 new objects -Andreas

Comment: I see no use of `Scanner` in the code. Please **edit** the question and show us what you've tried, and explain what *specific* problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to create Type name ArrayList then you will create Name.java class and Like modelClass and define variable if you want i define code showing below.

```
    public class Name {
        public String FirstName;
        public String FamilyName;
    
        public String getFirstName() {
            return FirstName;
        }
    
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            FirstName = firstName;
        }
    
        public String getFamilyName() {
            return FamilyName;
        }
    
        public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
            FamilyName = familyName;
        }
    }
```

2. After that you will call Your model call in MainMethod and define ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Name> register = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i <4 ; i++) {
                
     Name objt = new Name();
        objt.setFirstName(firstName);
        objt.getFamilyName(familyName );
        register.add(objt);
    }
```

after this code if you want to showing data(like print/log) then write down below this code

```
    for (int i = 0; i <register.size() ; i++) {
        System.out.println(register.get(i).getFullName());
    }
```

I hope this code is your use-full!